# Android assemble build is messing up GUI

Tags: android, gradle, build

I have the following fragment interface:

[image]

that shows fine when running the app from Android Studio. However when I run the build with assemble (e.g. assembleDebug), the interface is messed up like this:

[image]

This is the layout XML for the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.blablabla.presentation.vehicleinspection.viewmodel.VehicleCheckDamagesBottomSheetViewmodel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space_large">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:padding="@dimen/space_small">

            <TextView
                style="@style/TextMedium.Light"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/space_special"
                android:text="@{viewmodel.title}"
                tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_normal"
            app:adapter="@{viewmodel.adapter}"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:spanCount="2"
            app:useDefaultMargins="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the recycler view item layout was present in another linked library with the same name. Modifying the name of the layout solved the conflict and the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check in your app/src/debug folder, when you assemble a specific build variant, it will check that variant's assets first.

Possibly you have a different res/values/dimens.xml file and value in there compared to what is in app/src/main

Comment: Thanks, that was close. I had the same name for the recycler view item layout in another library that was causing the problem.